# multiple files for reading and saving

Tags: r, heatmap

I have multiple files to read and also do heatmap after which the outputs will be saved. Somehow, there is a problem(s) with my code below and I can't figure out why it is not working. Files: mxn.dat, scu.dat, emun.dat, ser.dat

```
files <- list.files(pattern=".dat")
for (i in length(files)){
data <-read.table(files[i],row.names=1,header=T,sep='\t')
  for in length(files){
  png('i.png') 
  pheatmap(t(data[i]), cellwidth = 32, cellheight = 14, fontsize = 5, show_colnames =  T, cluster_cols = FALSE)
  dev.off()
  } 
}
```

Any help will be appreciated to get the code working.

Thanks

Rob

Comment: `for in length(files){` doesn't look normal to me

Comment: also `"i.png"` will not evaluate to, for example, `"1.png"`. You need to use `paste0()` for that.

Comment: if `length(files)` equals say 10, you are saying `for( i in 10 ){...`, you mean `1:length(files)`

Comment: Hi, since you are relatively new here you might want to read the [**about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and the [**faq**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) about how SO works. StackOverflow is made much more valuable to everyone if when you receive an answer that solves your problem, you accept it by clicking the little check mark or upvote a useful answer. You are under absolutely no obligation to do either, but it is a great way to "give back" to the site if an answer did in fact solve your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a reproducible example so I have no way to test if this will work (and somehow I think that this is too localised to be useful to future visitors), but perhaps try this...

```
files <- list.files(pattern=".dat")

for (i in 1:length(files)){
  data <-read.table( files[i],row.names=1,header=T,sep='\t')
  png( paste0( i , '.png' ) )
    pheatmap( t( data ), cellwidth = 32, cellheight = 14, fontsize = 5, show_colnames =  T, cluster_cols = FALSE)
  dev.off()
  }
```

Comment: Thanks SimonO101 and Vaettchen. The code now works with simon's changes, but the saved output file names are are 1.png,2.png, 3.png and 4.png. I was looking for a way to save the output files with the corresponding names of input files ( mxn.png, scu.png, emun.png, ser.png)

Answer (score 0):

Variation of SimonO101's solution:

```
files <- list.files(pattern=".dat")

for( f in files )
{
  data <-read.table( f, row.names = TRUE, header = TRUE, sep = '\t' )
  png( gsub( "pdf", "png", f ) )
  pheatmap( t( data ), cellwidth = 32, cellheight = 14, fontsize = 5, show_colnames =  T,    cluster_cols = FALSE)
  dev.off()
}
```

Easier to read (I believe) and has the advantage (?) of preserving the original file names, only changing the extension.